# Cron number of messages on server queue

Tags: cron

I run a dedicated server but has been prone to spammers. I want a script I can run as a CRON every hour to send me an email on how many messages there are in the mail queue such as the command "pfHandle -s"

Server support suggest calling this from a php script.

I have tried this but says pfHandle: command not found

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('pfHandle -s');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

I executed this from cron as php -dsafe_mode=Off -q /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/chkmail.php

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a PHP script for this, unless you want to do some custom formatting? If not, you can pipe the output of your `pfHandle` script:

```
0 * * * pfHandle -s | mail -s "Mailqueue at the moment" [your@email]
```

Comment: Thanks but getting /bin/sh: pfHandle: command not found. I am on plesk 11, do I have to prefix some sh exec command?

Comment: Can you execute this `pfHandle -s` command when you are logged in? If so, you could execute `which pfHandle` to see what the full path is of the file. If you can't execute that command, I'd suggest using a different command (for example, `mailq`).

Comment: /usr/sbin/pfHandle pathname works and received an email but says zero messages but there are some. Sorry to ask but running this cron as system user apache but should this be something else?

Comment: You could try running it as user `root`. I don't know if `pfHandle` requires special privileges